# Laravel HasMany Relation is returning all models, not related ones

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.5, I have a Movie model:

```
  
    class Movie extends Model
    {
        public function comments(){
            return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
        }
    }
```

and a Comment model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function movie(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Movie::class);
    }
}
```

I have a movie instance (stored in $movie variable):

```
id: "tt5726616",
     title: "Call Me by Your Name",
     original_title: "Call Me by Your Name",
     rate: 4,
     year: 2017,
     length: "132",
     language: "English, Italian, French, German",
     country: "Italy, France, Brazil, USA",
     director: "Luca Guadagnino",
     created_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:31",
     updated_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:31",
```

and I have 4 comments, 2 of them related to the corresponding movie:

```
all: [
       App\Comment {#788
         id: 1,
         movie_id: "tt3967856",
         author: "user1",
         comment: "cool!",
         rate: 2,
         created_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
         updated_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
       },
       App\Comment {#786
         id: 2,
         movie_id: "tt3967856",
         author: "user2",
         comment: "not bad!",
         rate: 3,
         created_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
         updated_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
       },
       App\Comment {#785
         id: 3,
         movie_id: "tt5726616",
         author: "user1",
         comment: "cool!",
         rate: 4,
         created_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
         updated_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
       },
       App\Comment {#784
         id: 4,
         movie_id: "tt5726616",
         author: "user2",
         comment: "not bad!",
         rate: 5,
         created_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
         updated_at: "2018-01-21 15:28:32",
       },
     ],
```

the problem is, when I call $movie->comments, it returns all my 4 comments, not just those two with movie_id tt3967856. What should I do?

**SOLVED:** 
I think that was because I was using string type for my primary and foreign keys. I changed ids to integer (I mean 1,2,... instead of "tt3967856" etc.) and everything worked fine :D

Comment: Could you show result of `dd(Movie::with('comments')->find(1));`

Comment: It returns null. I also tried Movie::find(1) and it's null again.

Comment: Sorry, use the real ID  `tt3967856` instead of `1`. So, what does `dd(Movie::with('comments')->find('tt3967856'));` show?

Comment: It shows movie information for this ID + this:
 comments: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#801
       all: [],

Comment: Strange enough, I changed IDs to integers instead of IMDb IDs and migrated, and it's OK now.

Answer (score 0):

What if you specify foreign and local keys

```
class Movie extends Model
{
   protected $casts=['movie_id'=>'integer'];

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,movie_id,id);
    }
}
```

**update**:
I also noticed that `movie_id` has *string* type in comment object

You sbould cast it to integer